# Is there any way to receive Paytm payments with different persons at random?

Tags: android, paytm

We have around 500 distributors. Customers while pay with paytm we plan to receive his payment with his distributor. Is it possible? Suggest me for better approach. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I think you should contact the customer support of that particular company . It seems not about programming .

Comment: You can drop an email at : payments.onboarding@paytm.com